# Mapping Model nowhere to be found (Cocoa Error 134140)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data-migration

Basically, I have a Versioned `xcdatamodel` and I am migrating from V2 to V3

I created a `Mapping Model` with a custom policy.

Once the `PersistenStoreCoordinator` tries to do its job, I hit a **Cocoa Error No. 134140 (can't find mapping model for migration)**

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783197/cant-find-mapping-model-for-migration-where-does-the-mapping-model-have-to-go) basically is the same one I'm having but I am using **Xcode 4.6.3**

Things I have tried:

- Forcing the `xcmappingmodel` to reside inside the `xcdatamodelId` and  ensuring my mapping model is not 0kb in size as per the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369872/core-data-migration-cant-find-mapping-model-for-migration)
- Removing the `xcdatamodelId` references from Xcode and adding them back [(answer of this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782570/cant-find-mapping-model-for-migration-uimanageddocument-core-data-migration)
- Clean and Clean Build Folder options

**EDIT** Here are my debug statements if anyone is interested...

```
Handling DB Upgrade
sourceMetadata is {
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    OriginalPicture = <ce8de6ad c694b569 dcc1d706 d4df3928 05052cab 14a092f1 340cbf01 2306e861>;
    PanoramicInfo = <923298fa 0af16c01 d5ba91ca 19c6252c 8adee68a bfe7b86b 75285500 6883a1aa>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "F83640F3-8686-438F-97CC-48311EB74B9C";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}

Not Compatible Models Migration is NEEDED!
SourceEntity: OriginalPicture: <ce8de6ad c694b569 dcc1d706 d4df3928 05052cab 14a092f1 340cbf01 2306e861>
DestinationEntity: OriginalPicture: <ce8de6ad c694b569 dcc1d706 d4df3928 05052cab 14a092f1 340cbf01 2306e861>
SourceEntity: PanoramicInfo: <923298fa 0af16c01 d5ba91ca 19c6252c 8adee68a bfe7b86b 75285500 6883a1aa>
DestinationEntity: PanoramicInfo: <1d7836cd f3ccf5fa 487c1984 e2b3f46c abc3b706 c06512d5 0bac698c a5d8cb20>
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134140.)
```

**Second EDIT**

I've been trying to get the Mapping Model directly by using:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Update23Model" withExtension:@"cdm"];
```

But strangely fileURL points to nil.....

How do you add the mapping model to the bundle then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an **Xcode 4.6.3** bug...
The `xcmappingmodel` must not be inside any group folder it seems....

When I created it at the root level of the xcode project, the mapping was found by the IDE.

Comment: I can't believe the answer was this simple! Did the trick for me! I was getting ready to revert back to old core data model and recreate new one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079813/1678437) fix your problem ? The problem seems similar, sorry if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks... I did log and the hash of source is the same I get from sourceMetaData, while the hash of destination differs... still doesn't find the mapping model

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your test device's store is from a version of the data model that no longer exists.

For example I had Data Model Version 7, then I made Data Model Version 8. I made a mapping model to go from 7 to 8. Then I made some more changes to 8. When I open that app, it will give this error because the version of 8 that the mapping model was based on, no longer exists.