# NSFetchedResultsController Fatal Error When Working with CoreData (Attempt Fetch)

Tags: ios, swift

My app is crashing and giving me a fatal error that doesn't really tell me anything so I don't know what could be happening.

Here's the section of my code that's giving me trouble.

```
var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Item>!


func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest:  NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

    let mainController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    self.controller = mainController

    do {
        try mainController.performFetch()
    } catch {

        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")

    }

}
```

It crashes at

```
let mainController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

And "context" is referencing the app delegate

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

The error is :

> fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "(null)" UserInfo={sourceModel=() isEditable 1, entities {
>   "Crash on line 70 of the app delegate"

Thanks for your help

Comment: `controller` (`NSFetchedResultsController`) is supposed to be a lazy instantiated property in the class as suggested by Apple in the Core Data template.

Comment: @vadian Could you provide the link for the Apple documentation where it says that it's supposed to be lazy instantiated?

Comment: Just create a new (Master-Detail) project with Core Data enabled and study the provided code.

Comment: @vadian I know how the demo products look, but where is the documentation for how it is supposed to be and that it should make any difference not doing a lazy instantiating? I am asking out of personal interest since I have not read this anywhere and IF this is true what you say ,I might have to redo some work in my own project. But as far as I know, everything works fine for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150816/mapping-model-nowhere-to-be-found-cocoa-error-134140

Comment: @Sneak I assume the suggested code in the template is the code to be supposed. Even in the older Objective-C version the results controller is created lazily. Additionally in Swift the lazy instantiation makes the property non-optional which is another benefit.

Comment: @vadian Well, I want to know why it isn't documented and what differences it makes. Just because the demo templates or demo code provides with some code doesn't mean it has to be done that way, for some cases it might. I tried to google madly and couldn't find one single thing about it. Also, reading their documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller?language=objc you can see the example code there if you scroll down a bit, not a single word or code mentioned about this, so I guess it does not make any difference.

Comment: Try this inside of the do block: try self.controller.performFetch()

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running this fetch in your `AppDelegate` methods, I suspect that you are trying to do your `fetch` **before** your CoreData Persistent Store and it's contextes has been initialized resulting in the crash.